# How to check (branches or tags) from a remote git repository?

Tags: git

When I want to check, for examples, the tags in a git repo, I do `git branch` or `git tag`.
But this can be done in an already cloned repository. How can I check branches and tags in a remote git repo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[git ls-remote](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-remote)

To list all the refs in the remote repository:

```
git ls-remote <url_of_repository>
```

To list tags only:

```
git ls-remote --tags <url_of_repository>
```

To list branches only:

```
git ls-remote --heads <url_of_repository>
```

To list a specific ref:

```
git ls-remote <url_of_repository> <ref_name>
```

You don't have to be in a git repository to run this command. But if you are in a local repository, you could use a remote like `origin` instead of the long url. If you'd like to see the log of a ref, you still need to fetch it down to a local repository.